# iOS API TimeZone.current does not return actual system time

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, nstimezone

My iOS swift application calls
`TimeZone.current`
when the application comes to the foreground. If I manually change the timezone from Settings->General->Date&Time, and then bring my application to the foreground, I get the correct timezone. But if my timezone setting was set to automatic, and then I turn off the automatic, and bring back my application to the foreground, the `TimeZone.current` API does not reflect the new system timezone!

If I put the application to background and come back again to the foreground, this time it reflects the proper system timezone.
Is this a bug in iOS SDK? Is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [`NSTimeZone.local`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nstimezone/1387209-local), which is:

> An object that tracks the current system time zone.

You can also use the `NSTimeZone.system` property, but you'll need to manually call `NSTimeZone.resetSystemTimeZone()` to clear and refresh the current cached system timezone value.